# How to extract each line from a file, into separate files in Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux

How to extract each line from a file, into separate files in Linux

Example :

If the file content 10 rows, it will be 10 files.

if File contents
12345
1uthste
128766

First-line should move to 1.txt
Second-line should move to 2.txt
like this goes on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash)

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do? `in Linux Shell Script` Have you learned linux shell scripting? Maybe start with some good introduction, here is one: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide `How to extract each line from a file` Learn linux shell scripting and then write a script to do it. Alternatively you could hire a programmer or a person that would do it for you - for that see a freelancing site. Please kindly read [ask].